# Count Distinct - Inner Join - Group By / With the new Linq-to-NHibernate Provider

Tags: sql, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

**How would you write this exact SQL query with the new Linq-to-NHibernate Provider (3.x)**

```
SELECT Post.Title, COUNT(DISTINCT Comment.UserId)
FROM Post
INNER JOIN Comment ON Post.Id = Comment.PostId
GROUP BY Post.Title
```

**Here is some SQL if you want to make some tests**

```
DECLARE @Post Table(Id int identity(1,1), Title varchar(200))
DECLARE @Comment Table(Id int identity(1,1), PostId int, Comment varchar(200), UserId int)

DECLARE @PostId int

INSERT INTO @Post(Title)
VALUES ('Test')

SELECT @PostId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO @Comment(PostId, Comment, UserId)
VALUES (@PostId, 'Test Comment', 1)

INSERT INTO @Comment(PostId, Comment, UserId)
VALUES (@PostId, 'Test Comment 2', 1)

INSERT INTO @Comment(PostId, Comment, UserId)
VALUES (@PostId, 'Test Comment 3', 2)

INSERT INTO @Post(Title)
VALUES ('Test 2')

SELECT @PostId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO @Comment(PostId, Comment, UserId)
VALUES (@PostId, 'Test Comment', 1)

INSERT INTO @Comment(PostId, Comment, UserId)
VALUES (@PostId, 'Test Comment 2', 2)

INSERT INTO @Comment(PostId, Comment, UserId)
VALUES (@PostId, 'Test Comment 3', 3)


SELECT Post.Title, COUNT(DISTINCT Comment.UserId)
FROM @Post Post
INNER JOIN @Comment Comment ON Post.Id = Comment.PostId
GROUP BY Post.Title
```

Comment: How far did you get yourself? StackOverflow is for helping with problems, not for doing your work. No offense, but a bit more context would help in this case ;)

Comment: Given the fact that the question is very simple and that I took the time to produce the entire SQL, I think this question does not deserve this kind of comment. I just started using NHibernate and I don't even know where to start from. I thought this question would be easy for any NHibernate guru...

Comment: You might try posting on the nhusers group http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers what version of nh are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's currently possible to do the `count(distinct x)` part.

This is the closest I got:

```
from comment in session.Query<Comment>()
group comment by comment.Post.Title
      into g
      select new
             {
                 Title = g.Key,
                 Count = g.Select(x => x.UserId).Distinct().Count()
             };
```

But it produces exactly the same SQL as:

```
from comment in session.Query<Comment>()
group comment by comment.Post.Title
      into g
      select new
             {
                 Title = g.Key,
                 Count = g.Count()
             };
```

Which is:

```
SELECT Post.Title, COUNT(*)
FROM Comment
LEFT JOIN Post ON Post.Id = Comment.PostId
GROUP BY Post.Title
```

You should post an issue to http://jira.nhforge.org. There's a lot of work going on with the Linq provider and there's a good chance to get this construct supported in the near future.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! After some attempts I came to the same conclusion. Even worse, this was a simplified example of the problem I am facing. I will start a new question with the complete query and ask for the best way (not just Linq-To-NHibernate) of doing it with NHibernate.

Comment: Here is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351683/how-can-i-do-this-query-with-nhibernate