# How can I do this query with NHibernate

Tags: sql, nhibernate

**How can I do this query with NHibernate**

```
select top 10 count(distinct classedition.createdby_id) as editions, class.id,
       class.name, class.createdon, class.createdby_id
from class 
inner join classedition on class.id = classedition.class_id
group by class.id, class.name, class.createdon, class.createdby_id
order by editions desc, class.createdon desc
```

**I'm using NHibernate 3.** I tried to do it with the new Linq provider without success. I don't care about the way of doing it as long as it produce the exact sql query above. I would prefer writing a strongly typed query, without magic string if possible.

I'm new to NHibernate so this question may be simple.

**Here is a little more info**

I use Fluent NHibernate with AutoMappings. The C# classes are very simple:

```
public  class Class
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}

public class ClassEdition
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Class Class { get; set; }
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved the problem by using a View.

I don't want to be rude, but it seems like the NHibernate community is more inclined to argue on the way I ask a question then responding to the question itself. See the comments for Diego Mijelshon's answer. I received the same reproaches (about using unit tests) on nhusers (Google Groups): http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/4c74269aefb918fc

Answer (score 0):

HQL queries are strongly typed and object oriented.

```
var results = session.CreateQuery(@"
              select count(distinct e.CreatedBy), c.Id,
                     c.Name, c.CreatedOn, c.CreatedBy
              from ClassEditions e
              join e.Class c
              group by c.Id, c.Name, c.CreatedOn, c.CreatedBy
              order by 1 desc, c.CreatedOn desc
              ")
              .SetMaxResults(10)
              .List();
```

Your C# code is a string too. NH also has a query compiler.

In fact, if you put the query in a mapping file, you can even get intellisense and real-time error checking by installing the [HQL Language Service for Visual Studio](http://hqladdin.codeplex.com/).

And a simple unit test that does nothing more than build the SessionFactory will tell you if anything broke because of a change. Not to mention modern refactoring tools (like Resharper) are able to rename identifiers in strings, bindings, or any kind of files without a problem.

Comment: This is not what I meant by "strongly typed" since it is a plain old string. If the table "Class" is renamed there will be nothing preventing the application from compiling. But I think (haven't tried it yet) it is doing what I want. I will wait a bit for possible alternatives before accepting this answer.

Comment: Can you add your classes and mappings so we can help?

Comment: Exactly, I need intellisense and real-time error checking or I would use PHP - joking. I don't like to have to write unit tests (even though I do most of the time) to know if my code is broken, compiling should take care of that. But installing add-ins is starting to be a bit far fetch (in my humble opinion). Finally, I use ReSharper and I don't think renaming a property in my model would result in modifying a string - or if I would let it do that, it would be risky for collateral damages (modifying things I don't necessarily want to). Sorry for my poor english, it is not my first language.

Comment: All and all, I think what I am trying to say is simply that there is a reason why Linq is so popular. If I can't do what I want with the current Linq provider, is there something nearer to Linq than a loosely typed query in the NHibernate world?

Comment: I was trying to write a QueryOver for this... but if you think the compiler replaces unit testing, I won't encourage lousy programming practices.

Comment: I don't think I said that the compiler replaces unit testing... I even said that I am using unit testing - but strongly typed code should have the advantages of... strongly typed languages! I tried the query you suggested and it did not work. The grouping part fails - it seems related to the fact that CreatedBy is a relation to a User. I tried adding the fields of User to the grouping part but it did not work.